# Not able to make bootstrap dropdown menu work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to make bootstrap dropdown menus work for myself. The dropdown menus are not visible when clicked on it. I have kept this as my dropdown HTML code

```
<div class="dropdown">                                                 
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Time period
    </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" v-bind:class="{ active: timeFilter==='7D' }" v-on:click="timeFilter='7D';updateCharts()">7 Days New</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" v-bind:class="{ active: timeFilter==='1M' }" v-on:click="timeFilter='1M';updateCharts()">1 month</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" v-bind:class="{ active: timeFilter==='3M' }" v-on:click="timeFilter='3M';updateCharts()">3 months</a>
            
            </div>
    </div>
```

I have included following includes at the end

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

THis setup is now hosted at http://51.195.233.107/ if you want to check any other CSS/JS codes disabling the execution

Thanks for your help. I am stuck on this for last 5-6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I have used the bootstrap 4.0.0 version.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Time period
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" v-bind:class="{ active: timeFilter==='7D' }" v-on:click="timeFilter='7D';updateCharts()">7 Days New</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" v-bind:class="{ active: timeFilter==='1M' }" v-on:click="timeFilter='1M';updateCharts()">1 month</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" v-bind:class="{ active: timeFilter==='3M' }" v-on:click="timeFilter='3M';updateCharts()">3 months</a>

        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Nagendra.. But somehow this is not working. I finally wrote a code to give class "open" when someone clicks on the button and now that seems to be working. I am still not getting why default modules are not working.